# DocumentBuilder.parse(InputStream) error - missing type

Tags: java, eclipse, xml-parsing

I've been trying to make a discord bot for some time and I'm currently trying to user reddit's api to get an XML file. However, when I'm trying to parse to file, DocumentBuilder.parse(InputStream) Eclipse shows the following error.

"The method parse(InputStream) from the type DocumentBuilder refers to the missing type InputStream"

I've messed around a bit but I can't find a way to deal with it. I also haven't found any answers online after some thorough Googling.

Here is my code:

```
try {
        URL url = new URL(REDDIT_URL + URL);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection(); //not needed

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(url.openStream());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error using Java 9.0.1+11 and http://httpbin.org/xml as a source URL returning XML.  It works fine for me.  You may have a missing or corrupted jar file.  Please [edit] your post and include the COMPLETE stack trace, including all CAUSED BY sections (formatted as code, please).

Comment: Might be useful to see your imports also.